# Route CSS and Yarn with Sylius 1.12

Tags: css, symfony, yarnpkg, sylius

I installed the last version of Sylius (1.12.7) this week.

I installed Composer, node, Wampserver and yarn.

Sylius install is a success and `yarn install` / `yarn build` is ok (some warning messages when I launched `yarn install`, I don't know if it's a big problem but the build command work correctly).

My problem : CSS and images are not charged when I launch my website.

I check the source code of my index page and I see that css and images redirecting to `localhost/build/shop/shop-entry.css` instead of `localhost/MYPROJECT/public/build/shop/shop-entry.css`.

I tested with adding the css file in `localhost/build/shop/shop-entry.css` and the application is launched correctly with the css in this file.

In addition, if I update setPublicPath in webpack.config.js in the root of my project the CSS works correctly

```
.setPublicPath('/MYPROJECT/public/build/shop')
```

Instead of

```
.setPublicPath('/build/shop')
```

I don't know where is the problem : yarn install is not correct ? yarn build is not ok ? others configurations ?

Many thanks everybody :)